# Api request not working on development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I have rails app and i have event controller

```
def create          
            @event = Event.create(event_params) 
            @event.location_id = Location.find_by_address(params[:address]).id
            @event.owner = current_user

            if params[:clot_id].present?
                @event.clot_id = params[:clot_id]
            end         
            render json: @event, status: 201, location: @event              
        end


def event_params
            params.require(:event).permit(:venue, :clot_id, :contact, :cost, :description, :name, :tag_list,:location_id,   
                    compound_started_at_attributes: [:date, :time],
                    compound_ended_at_attributes: [:date, :time], location_attributes: [:id, :address])
        end
```

When i try to make curl request on localhost its working fine

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: Token token'="NXNW8kxzZ2z8czHF6" -X POST -d 'event[venue]=indore&event[contact]=9977966105&event[cost]=52&event[name]=forencis&event[compound_started_at_attributes][date]= 2015-08-20&event[compound_started_at_attributes][time]= 09.05&event[compound_ended_at_attributes][date]= 2015-08-25&event[compound_ended_at_attributes][time]= 10.05&event[location_id]=10&event[clot_id]=26' http://localhost:3000/api/events
```

curl to server

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: Token token'="oKSMrppRXEiRSH61okn5" -X POST -d 'event[venue]=indore&event[contact]=9977966105&event[cost]=52&event[name]=forencis&event[compound_started_at_attributes][date]= 2015-08-20&event[compound_started_at_attributes][time]= 09.05&event[compound_ended_at_attributes][date]= 2015-08-25&event[compound_ended_at_attributes][time]= 10.05&event[location][address]=indore&event[clot_id]=1' 104.236.233.57/api/events
```

But when i m trying to make same curl request to production server its giving error in production.log

```
F, [2015-07-02T14:20:47.041280 #29752] FATAL -- :
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/api/events_controller.rb:34:in `create
```

i.e error in line

> @event.location_id = Location.find_by_address(params[:address]).id

I checked the database for the presence of location_id = 10 in production database and i also checked other values in database before sending api request.

Please help me solve the error.

Comment: You should be using your strong parameters `event_params` to access all values from your view.  I know you said this is working fine in some cases, but I do not see where you are permitting `params[:address]`.

Comment: @steveklein i have location_attributes: [:id, :address]) in permit

Comment: i agree with steve. toss a debugger or binding.pry into your Location.find_by_address method and inspect the argument that is being passed in. It's likely nil.

Answer (score 1):

you're using the `:address` param and in the query string, address is inside location param: `event[location][address]=indore`.

Shouldn't be `event[address]=indore`?

And your code assumes that always 'Location' will be found. You shouldn't assume that and add some validation to Event class (or other workaround that makes sense to you):

```
@event.location_id = Location.find_by_address(params[:address]).try(:id)
```

And in `Event` class:

```
class Event
  validates_presence_of :location_id
end
```